# Read rows/columns of numbers in a text file (c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, text, textbox

I have a text file with the following numbers for example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

How do I read each individual number into an array?

It needs to move along each row so read in 1, 2 and then 3 into a array of then move to the second row and read 4 5 and 6.. and show the number of cells in a textbox.

this is my code, but I got an error.

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] chars = lines[i].ToCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[j]))
                list2.Add(chars[j].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a jagged int array:

```
int[][] result = text
            .Split('\n')
            .Select(line => 
                line
                .Split(' ')
                .Select(numberText => int.Parse(numberText))
                .ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Iterate through like this:

```
foreach (int[] line in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", line)); // or iterate through its numbers again
                                                // or whatever you want to do
}
```

**Edit**

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

string path = "xy"; //your path
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

int[][] result = lines
            .Select(line => 
                line
                .Split(' ')
                .Select(numberText => int.Parse(numberText))
                .ToArray()).ToArray();

foreach (int[] line in result)
{
    list2.Add(string.Join(", ", line)); // or whatever format you want the text to be
}
```

Comment: do list2.Add(string.join(...)) and it should work with your existing code too... alternative replace text.Split('\n') with your lines if you used File.ReadAllLines

Comment: could you please tell me, where should I change?

Comment: it is clear thanks, and If I want to show the number of cells in the textbox?

Comment: @ Florian Schmidinger: I received this message :

Comment: Use line.Length? the Length of an Array would be the amount of values.

Comment: @AH2012 and you get the exception because @"label3.Text" is not a valid path... use just label3.Text

Comment: @AH2012 and use absolute paths... or relative paths

Comment: @AH2012 if it solved the issue please be so kind to accept the answer... we both get a little reputation and other users can see that the issue is solved, so it benefits us all. and no need to say thank you... but you are perfectly welcome =)

Comment: Do you know how can I count the number in my text file, I use this line but it shows the wrong number since I have 416, but it shows 2.  int n= lines.Count();
               MessageBox.Show (n.ToString());

Comment: @AH2012 so you want to count all numbers? meaning all numbers in all rows? ... btw accepting the answer works with the little checksymbol link next to the answer...

Comment: Yes, I want to know how many numbers we have in the text if we look at each of the as a cell, then I would like to know the number of cells .

Comment: @AH2012 try:  int totalCount = result.SelectMany(x => x).Count();

Comment: @AH2012 SelectMany flattens the jagged array into a normal IEnumerable<int> means a single list of integers... that you can .Count()

Comment: @AH2012 as i said, no need to say thank you... but please accept the answer (checksymbol to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    label3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(label3.Text);
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(label3.Text);
    string[] lines = new StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    fs.Close();
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] chars = lines[i].ToCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[j]))
                list2.Add(chars[j].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```